# How to use pipe %>% in R with dollar sign?

Tags: r, pipe

My question is that I wish to use pipes to simplify my codes. But in one of the steps, I only want to extract and continue with one of the elements in my data.
Please see the code below for more details

```
data1 <-coef(df)
data2 <-as.data.frame(data1$a)
```

So I need to run a function called 'coef', that will return a list of results, say, 'a,b,c,d', but I am only interested in 'a'. And normally I will store the full results, then store the results that I'm interested using a dollar sign $. But I wonder if I can also do in pipe,something similar to the codes below, but it apparently wouldn't work for now.

```
data2<-df %>%
  coef() %>%
  select(a) %>%
  as.data.frame ()
```

Comment: Something like this? `mtcars %>% .$mpg`

Comment: If a is a vector (or column) in your data frame, you can extract the results with df %>% dplyr::pull(a). This would be like typing df$a. I’m not entirely sure that’s what you want to do though.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that the question is asking how to extract a column from a data frame.  Later we assume the alternative that it is asking how to pick out one coefficient from the built-in `coef` acting on an `lm` model.  Next time please provide a complete reproducible code and inputs so we can be sure what is being asked.

Here are several ways using the built-in BOD data frame.

```
library(magrittr)

BOD %$% Time
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

BOD %>% extract2("Time")
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

   
# can use library(magrittr) or library(dplyr) for any of these

BOD %>% with(Time)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

BOD %>% .$Time
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7

BOD %>% .subset2("Time")
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7
 
BOD %>% .[["Time"]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7


library(dplyr)
BOD %>% pull(Time)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 7
```

If what was meant in the question was that `coef` is extracting coefficients from an lm model and we want one of them then we have the following which are the same except that in some cases we need to add `as.list` to the pipeline.

```
library(magrittr)

# this is used by all the pipelines below
co <- BOD %>% lm(demand ~ Time, .) %>% coef


co %>% as.list %$% Time
## [1] 1.721429

co %>% extract2("Time")
## [1] 1.721429

# can use library(magrittr) or library(dplyr) for any of these

co %>% as.list %>% with(Time)
## [1] 1.721429

co %>% as.list %>% .$Time
## [1] 1.721429

co %>% .subset2("Time")
## [1] 1.721429
 
co %>% .[["Time"]]
## [1] 1.721429
```

Comment: There is also `pluck`

Answer (score 1):

`coef()` gives you a vector, so `$` is not applicable. But you may use `getElement()`.

```
lm(mpg ~ am + hp, mtcars) |>
  coef() |>
  getElement('am') 
# [1] 5.277085
```

Works also with `magrittr` pipes `%>%` of course.